# Autolayout layoutSubviews called when changing frames

Tags: ios, autolayout, layoutsubviews

Here is an analysis of how things work and I wish I could find an explanation for this behaviour without having to read the entire Internet about Auto Layout on iOS6+.

I have 3 similar scenarios, depicted in following images. The only difference is how they layout views `viewA` and `viewB`:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

In each scenario, ViewController calls `moveGrandchild` method several times per second. In that method, it grabs a view that is not an immediate child of self.view, and sets a new frame to it. A new frame is different from the previous only by `origin.x` value. One would expect that a `viewB` would constantly move towards right side of the screen, and that is exactly what happens. The difference, though, is when `layoutSubviews` is called in each scenario.

Here are the console outputs for each scenario:

1)

2013-11-08 11:31:27.048 ProbaAutoLayout[3641:907] VC viewDidLayoutSubviews

2013-11-08 11:31:27.052 ProbaAutoLayout[3641:907] ViewA layoutSubviews

2013-11-08 11:31:27.054 ProbaAutoLayout[3641:907] ViewB layoutSubviews

2013-11-08 11:31:27.240 ProbaAutoLayout[3641:907] ViewA layoutSubviews

2013-11-08 11:31:27.439 ProbaAutoLayout[3641:907] ViewA layoutSubviews

2013-11-08 11:31:27.639 ProbaAutoLayout[3641:907] ViewA layoutSubviews

... repeats indefinitely ...

2)

2013-11-08 11:34:06.532 ProbaAutoLayout[3658:907] VC viewDidLayoutSubviews

2013-11-08 11:34:06.536 ProbaAutoLayout[3658:907] ViewA layoutSubviews

2013-11-08 11:34:06.539 ProbaAutoLayout[3658:907] ViewB layoutSubviews

3) 
*same as 2)*

In each scenario, viewB is performing its continuous movement to the right with no stopping. Only in the first case, `layoutSubviews` on `viewA` (`viewB`'s parent) is being repeatedly called.

When an image says: `// frame set explicitly`, that means that a view was created with `initWithFrame:` and no constraint were created that would involve that view. When it says: `// frame determined by autolayout using constraints`, it means that constraints involving that view were added to its parent view.

**The question is: why is layoutSubviews being called on viewA every time I change frame of viewB in scenario 1 but not on any others?**

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I edited the original question and bolded the exact question in the end...

Comment: Is `ViewA layoutSubviews` printed after every change of `_viewB.x` or does it go into an infinite loop?

Comment: There is no infinite loop. layoutSubviews is called only once after each change on _viewB's frame.